# Using Nginx to rewrite a friendly URL to index.php handler gives 404 errors

Tags: url-rewriting, nginx, error, clean-urls

I am having some issues getting the below to work the way I expect.  What I am trying to do is take a url like

```
https://example.com/TOPIC/courses/details/143911
```

but have it sent to php with the URI like

```
/index.php?/product/details/143911&original_path=/TOPIC/courses/details/143911.
```

It just seems to keep giving me 404's.

```
location ~ ^(?P<one>.*)/(?P<two>details|scheduler)/(?P<three>.*)$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?/product/$two/$three&original_path=$one;
}

location ~* \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_URL $my_script_url;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_URI $scheme://$http_host$my_script_url;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PHP_SELF $uri;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS $https if_not_empty;
    fastcgi_param HTTP_FRONT_END_HTTPS HTTPS;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $uri?$args;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_ignore_headers "Cache-Control";
    fastcgi_ignore_headers "Expires";
    fastcgi_ignore_headers "Set-Cookie";
}
```

What is strange is that I can put the URL in like

```
https://example.com/index.php?/product/details/143911&orignial_path=/TOPIC/courses
```

and it works fine.

Something else that seems strange to me is that if I implement the php-fpm status page each request, via the `try_files` above or entering the URL manually shows the same script and `request_uri`, but only the manually entry is working how I would expect.

Comment: That second `?` is unusual - usually `&` is used to join elements of a query string. I wonder if encountering two `?`s is confusing `try_files`.